# Converting a file to UTF8 format using Perl

Tags: perl, format, utf-8

How do I convert a file to its utf-8 format using Perl? and how do I check whether the converted file is in utf-8 format?

Comment: Please reduce the amount of caps in your question title.
It will certainly not get it answered faster.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612244/how-can-i-convert-an-input-file-to-utf-8-encoding-in-perl

Answer (score 3):

Installing bindings to the `iconv` library such as `Text::Iconv` is not necessary because Perl already comes with a character encoding library on its own: [`Encode`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encode/). Part of it is [`piconv`](http://p3rl.org/piconv), an `iconv(1)` workalike. Use it to batch convert files to UTF-8. **ANSI** is just a stupid name for the group of `windows-125?` encodings. You most likely have files encoded in [windows-1252](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets#windows-1252). Example:

```
piconv -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8 < input-file > output-file
```

If metadata are missing, heuristics have to be used to determine the encoding of a file content. [I have been recommending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970660#1974459) [`Encode::Detect`](http://p3rl.org/Encode::Detect::Detector).

Answer (score 2):

To do converting, take a look on [Text::Iconv](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Iconv)

```
  use Text::Iconv;
  $converter = Text::Iconv->new("fromcode", "tocode");
  $converted = $converter->convert("Text to convert");
```

Comment: thanks Mark... but I couldnt figure out how exactly to use these lines.. I have a file in ANSI FORMAT which has to saved in UTF8 FORMAT.. when I am using utf8 command, the resulting file is still in ANSI format(I checked it using notepad). any help?

Comment: @xyz, basically you need to read contents of your files and convert with Iconv or built-in Encode function as daxim mentioned and save it back. But if your files have only ascii characters <= 0x7F, you will see output files also same because ascii are valid utf8 too.

Comment: @xyz: ANSI is not a format, but a name used by Microsoft for a collection of encodings. You most likely have the encoding "windows-1252", so try converting from "windows-1252" to "UTF-8".

Comment: How do you know it's not UTF-8? Does it use any characters outside of ISO-646?

Comment: when I am using Text::Iconv;
I am getting error msg: 'Can't locate Text/Iconv.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/lib C:/Perl/site/lib
.)'.. Do I have install anything else?
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at uni1.pl line 1.

Comment: @xyz, could you try with built-in Encode function as @daxim mentioned? I am not sure how to install that in windows.

Answer (score 1):

that depends on the string you got. if it's a file been uploaded - i think this code will help. but if it's a text from web / text that converted itself to utf-8 ( because you're working on utf-8 ) then you'll have a problem figuring it out.

i usually use:

> use Encoding::Guess
>
> my $enc = guess_encoding($string);

and then with the above code, i do:

> use Text::Iconv;
> $converter = Text::Iconv->new($enc,"utf-8");
> $converted = $converter->convert("Text to convert");

FYI utf-8 list can be found here:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm?start=1024

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024&number=1024&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=dec

Comment: That module is Encode::Guess (http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encode/lib/Encode/Guess.pm)

Answer (score 1):

using Encode module you can easily encode in different encoding

e.g;

```
my $str = "A string in Perl internal format ....";
my $octets = encode("utf-8",$str,Encode::FB_CROAK);
```

to check for utf you can use function

```
is_utf8($str,Encode::FB_CROAK)
```

Comment: The Encode module is crappy because it doesn't correctly detect the input format, try it yourself with my $str = "ทดสอบ" in utf-8 then encode to ISO-8859-11