# File encoding for English and Chinese text

Tags: sql-server, perl, file-io, character-encoding

I am building a dynamic sql file that can have english characters and chinese/russian/vietnamese etc. Each text excerpt is in its own file and encoded properly. I need to be able to read in each of these files and output a single file that contains all these characters. I am using perl to read in and output the file.

My question has two parts.

1. What file encoding supports English text and Non-English text?
2. Using perl, can I convert the input file automatically into the above encoding format?

For part 2, I believe I need to read the file in the proper format to convert it. I have searched and found Encoding::Guess but not sure if this works and also not sure exactly how to use this.

I found this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612244/how-can-i-convert-an-input-file-to-utf-8-encoding-in-perl), the first answer explains a lot but not *how*?

Comment: I don't think you need to guess here. Familiarize yourself with your tool-set and learn to find out which encoding any of your files have. If you don't know for sure with what encoding you start, you don't even need to start.

Comment: Well, running Encode::Guess returns UTF-16BE for most of the asian text. I receive the files from a vendor and need to automate the import into the database. This is why I don't want to determine the file encoding manually but rather let the script handle it for me

Comment: Please don't guess unless your definition of fun is very, very strange. If you vendor distributes those files, I'm sure he'll be able to tell you which encoding they have.

Comment: Ok (I am new to perl) so lets say my vendor tells me  its in encoding X, how do I get it from that to lets say UTF8 (which I believe supports multiple languages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question in your last comment, here's how to convert from one encoding to another encoding:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub read_encoded {
    my $file_name = shift;
    my $encoding  = shift;

    my $content;
    if ( open my $fh, "<:encoding($encoding)", $file_name ) {
        $content = do {
            local $/;
            <$fh>;
        };
    }
    else {
        die "Could not open $file_name: $!";
    }

    return $content;
}

sub write_file {
    my $file_name = shift;
    my $content   = shift;

    if ( open my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $file_name ) {
        print $fh $content;
    }
    else {
        die "Could not open $file_name: $!";
    }
}

my $content1 = read_encoded( 'file1.txt', 'latin-1' );
my $content2 = read_encoded( 'file2.txt', 'UTF-16BE' );

write_file( 'output', $content1 . $content2 );
```

Assuming you have two files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, encoded in latin-1 und UTF-16BE, respecitively, this little script will read both files and write the output to a UTF-8-encoded file named `output`.

Comment: All that code is, like, 2 lines when using [File::Slurp](http://p3rl.org/File::Slurp).

Comment: @daxim: Why not add those lines to your answer, then?

Answer (score 2):

```
piconv -f UTF-16BE         -t UTF-8 < input-file > output-file
piconv -f $source_encoding -t UTF-8 < input-file > output-file
```

[piconv](http://p3rl.org/piconv), an [iconv](http://enwp.org/iconv) work-alike, is part of [Encode](http://p3rl.org/Encode) and ships with Perl.

To detect the source encoding, use better modules than Encode::Guess. See [How can I guess the encoding of a string in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970660/how-can-i-guess-the-encoding-of-a-string-in-perl)